# How to get siunitx to centre columns of integers correctly

Tags: tables, siunitx

I've just discovered `siunitx`, which seems to do what I want with tables, that is centering a column but keeping numbers decimal aligned. I find it doesn't work for a column of integers (say 99, 9, 99, 99). The numbers are correctly aligned among themselves, but are not centered correctly within the column, being shifted one or two positions to the left of where they should be. I'm using `siunitx` with no change of options, and just a plain {S} as the column type. It works fine for columns of numbers with decimal points, but it gets columns of integers wrong.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `table-format` option, to specify how much space to set aside for each part of the numbers in the table. If you have integers of up to, say, 3 digits, you can use `table-format=3` to set aside space for 3 integer digits, and no decimals.

As stated in the comments, this option can also be set on a per-column basis, by passing the options to the column definition when it is used.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \sisetup{
    table-format = 2,
  }
  \begin{tabular}{SSS}
    A  & B  & C  \\
    15 &  3 &  2 \\ 
    20 &  2 & 19 \\ 
    25 & 24 &  4 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{
      S[table-format=2.3] % with space for integers and decimals
      S[table-format=2]   % with space for integers only
      S                   % as the default
    }
    A  & B  & C  \\
    15 &  3 &  2 \\ 
    20 &  2 & 19 \\ 
    25 & 24 &  4 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here's how the aligned integers look:

[image]

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that you can also specify the table format for each column individually, using `S[table-format=2]` in the column specification.

Comment: True. Will add it into the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Adding tab;e-format to the S column type does the job. Puzzles me a bit why this is necessary, but this is a very minor query. Having only about a year ago discovered latex and all the associated packages, I think it's great. Whatever you want to do someone seems to have provided the necessary package. How did I ever get by with MSWord!

Comment: @MikeTanner Glad it worked. If this solved your problem, make sure to mark it as the accepted answer to show that it did.